# How does the R library "randomForest" order factor levels?

Tags: r, random-forest

So my question is, which level gets number 1, which one gets 2.. etc. I speculated that it could be the order in which they appear in the input / alphabetically, but none of these seem to be correct.

I don't know much about R and Google can't help me on this particular question.

Comment: not clear: do you mean whether/how visualization functions (such as varImpPlot) in the randomForest *package* sort *variables* in the output? (for the above's default it is the order of decreasing importance)

Comment: Nope :). If a node in a tree chooses a categorical feature for splitting, it will provide a "split-point" in the form of an integer. All objects that are in category number C go to the left if the C-th bit of "split-point" is 1, otherwise they go to the right. My question is, how does R assign category _numbers_ to categories? If my feature is City, it'll have to give numbers to "New York", "London", "Berlin". I'm not sure how it decides to do that. How can I know to which town it's referring to by "1". How does it hash them.

Comment: shouldn't these be coded as dummy variables in order to get a meaningful classification (however it numbers them won't be truly numeric)?

Comment: Well I don't want them to be truly numeric. The number part is just for convenience inside the algorithm. Otherwise, an integer couldn't encode a subset :) Maybe I wasn't clear enough, this has nothing to do with the algorithmic part, it's just a technical detail of how R does things.